# Use Sqlite & Knex with Node Module

Tags: sqlite, electron

im building a desktop app with electron and use for that JS and jQuery. All of them are installed as modules and used with "require" . it works perfect.

Now i want my database with sqlite and knex and try to start the node server with the knex and sqlite db together with the app.

but the problem is, that knex cant find the sqlite module.

can someone help me?

```
HERE is the start

console.log('SQL - Datenbank-Server gestartet');

let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let knex = require('knex');

let server = app.listen(8286, function () {
console.log('DB Server running on port 8286');
});

let connection = knex({
client: 'sqlite3',
connection: {
    filename: './finanzverwaltung.db'
}
});

HERE is the Failure
 Server gestartet.
SQL - Datenbank-Server gestartet
Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module 'F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v70-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\knex.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\app\server\sql_server.js
Error: Cannot find module 'F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v70-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\knex.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\app\server\sql_server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:808:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Client_SQLite3._driver (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:44:12)
    at Client_SQLite3.initializeDriver (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:253:26)
    at Client_SQLite3.Client (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:84:10)
    at new Client_SQLite3 (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:31:19)
F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:257
      throw new Error(`${message}\n${e.message}`);
      ^

Error: Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module 'F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v70-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\knex.js
- F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\app\server\sql_server.js
    at Client_SQLite3.initializeDriver (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:257:13)
    at Client_SQLite3.Client (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:84:10)
    at new Client_SQLite3 (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:31:19)
    at Knex (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:57:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\app\server\sql_server.js:12:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:808:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:873:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Comment: Might be it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/56017492/5060008

Comment: hi thanks, but changed anything - still cant find module :


Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module 'F:\Projekte\finanzverwaltung\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v70-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

Comment: have you tried with `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source` ?

Comment: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/5911

Comment: not still an error:

`Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1`

node-pre-gyp errors...

Answer (score 0):

So finally i did it - and the solution is to use the electron-builder...

```
"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into problems when bundling sqlite together with electron. Electron builder will allow you to build electron for your platform architecture however will also have to be rebuilt for other systems attempting to run it. Once you have installed electron-rebuild via npm you can add the following script to your package.json.

```
"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
```

then run:

```
npm run rebuild
```

You might run into some additional errors for dependencies as I did on Windows needing Visual Studio build tools and python 2.

Here is a video tutorial I found on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c76FTxLRwAw&

Depending on your needs, instead of using sqlite directly with electron, an alternative would be to use a separate nodejs server to access your database which I found to be less of a headache.